# What does "les" mean here?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos

Please read the following sentence:

> Tras años de litigios, en tres semanas, esas monedas de oro y plata estarán en donde ***les*** corresponde es decir, en nuestro país.

What does "les" mean? If we don´t use "les", how can we rewrite the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Les" is a personal pronoun that works here as an indirect-object (dative). It refers here to the coins (monedas).

> "donde **les** corresponde (estar) = where it suits **them** (to be) = it's appropiate **for/to them** (to be)"

In this particular example, I think that the pronoun could be omitted "estarán donde corresponde" - it actually sounds a little better to me, the  meaning is slightly different (the verb "corresponder" refers more to the situation than to the coins: "where it's appropiate") but in this context it's equivalent.

Comment: @leonboy: I am still confused. In "appropriate for them", isn't "them" is the direct object? If it is the indirect object, who is the direct object? Thanks!

Comment: @Cadenza: i'm no expert in english grammar, i'm extrapolating from spanish... But i'd say it's the indirect object (the object of the dative case). Replace "to be appropiate for" with "to suit" or "to fit". In the phrase "This shirt fits you", "you" is the indirect object. The verb does not require a direct object, as it's not transitive.

Comment: @leonboy: Thanks for your explanation. I think I am a bit clear now. Could you please give me more similar examples?